Flutter: get access to data on multiple screen
I have a list of items from Firestore on one screen. On the second screen I'm using DefaultTabController where I have multiple taps. I want that when an item is selected from he first screen, all the tapscreens on the second screen should get access to the data of the selected item from the first screen. I have absolutely no idea on how to do that. Can anyone help me?


Dive yourself into State Management. Riverpod was already mentioned, but I'd go with simple provide-consumer pattern Flutter offers as such: https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

I will read about it and see if it helps. thanks

There are multiple ways to do this,
1. You can pass the data as an argument
In screen 2
final String selectedItem;
const Screen2({ required this.selectedItem });

and then in screen 1, pass the selected item
String selectedItem = "Item 1"

....

// if using navigator between the two screens
Navigator.pushNamed(context, <screen2_route>, arguments: selectedItem)

// if using screen2 as widget in screen1
Screen2({selectedItem: selectedItem})

....



2. Use flutter_riverpod
This is a state management library which uses provider-consumer concept. It is usually used with complex or asynchronous state management.
But can also be used in your case (not recommended)

Finally, it depends on the code structure, if these solutions does not resolve your query, please share code snippet by editing the question.

Thank you. The first solution would do only if I was accessing the data on only one screen. But what I want to do is the data should be accessible to all the tabs screens. When I tap on tab 1, I should access the data of the selected item 1, on the screen of tab 1, likewise when I tap on tab 2 I should access the data of the selected item 1. That's the selected item 1 should be accessible to all the screens of tabs 1-4.

Thank you. The first solution would do only if I was accessing the data on only one screen. But what I want to do is the data should be accessible to all the tabs screens. When I tap on tab 1, I should access the data of the selected item 1, on the screen of tab 1, likewise when I tap on tab 2 I should access the data of the selected item 1. That's the selected item 1 should be accessible to all the screens of tabs 1-4.

As samuli mentioned, you can try using provider. If still it does not resolve, please add a code snippet for better solutions.

Alright thanks. I'm yet to learn to use the provider as I'm not advanced in the flutter language

I've figured out how to go about this. Should I answer my own post for others who might have similar problem or there is no need for that?

Yes, that would be helpful.
